# Logic: Give a syntactic proof

Tags: logic

My first upper division logic class.

Use the deduction theorem to give a syntactic proof

$p\wedge q\vdash q\wedge p$

$\{(p\rightarrow (q\rightarrow \bot))\rightarrow \bot, q\rightarrow (p\rightarrow \bot)\}\vdash \bot$ from the deduction thm.

1. $(p\rightarrow (q\rightarrow \bot))\rightarrow \bot$      (premise)
2. $q\rightarrow (p\rightarrow \bot)$                        (premise)
3. $\bot$                                                      (Modus ponens)

Comment: @Derek Elkins I think I got it. Ill edit

Comment: For 3. : Modus ponens from what ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA from 1 and 2. Since  $(p\rightarrow (q\rightarrow \bot))\equiv q\rightarrow (p\rightarrow \bot)$

Comment: Yes, but what are the rules you are allowed to use ? If you can use $(p→(q→⊥))≡q→(p→⊥)$ why not also $(p∧q)≡(q∧p)$ ?

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I'm not sure. We jump around between 3 different languages. One of which has only $\bot$ and $\rightarrow$. So I've been following those examples. But he didn't state it in the question.